# R max function returns pseudo values when used within 'dplyr'

Tags: r, dplyr, max

I used R's max function in combination with the `summarise` function from the `dplyr` package and had a typo in the **`max`** function's argument `na.rm`.
Mistakenly I wrote `ns.rm = T` and the script worked without any warning message and returned wrong values. 
When replacing the `na.rm` with `ns.rm` on a simple vector (outside `dplyr` environment), the function returns the right values, and if the input vector holds `NA` then it returns an `NA` value without any warning about wrong argument used.

Here is an example:

```
if(!require('magrittr')) install.packges('magrittr')
if(!require('dplyr'))    install.packges('dplyr')

tab <- data.frame("grp1" = sort(rep(1:4, 5)), 
                  "grp2" = rep(c(1:2), 10),
                  "val" = rnorm(20))


tab

   grp1 grp2         val
1     1    1  0.03536351
2     1    2  1.04237251
3     1    1  0.82735937
4     1    2  0.29040424
5     1    1  0.30194926
6     2    2 -0.96649026
7     2    1 -0.97388257
8     2    2 -0.13111541
9     2    1 -0.48337864
10    2    2 -0.73471857
11    3    1 -0.88536656
12    3    2 -1.30442575
13    3    1  1.18816751
14    3    2 -0.90334058
15    3    1 -0.53102641
16    4    2 -0.69266762
17    4    1 -0.64776312
18    4    2  0.01354644
19    4    1  0.78058285
20    4    2 -0.06647959
> 
### Using max function within dplyr
## Right way

tab %>% 
  group_by(grp1, grp2) %>% 
  summarise("max_val" = max(val, na.rm = T))

 # A tibble: 8 x 3
    # Groups:   grp1 [4]
       grp1  grp2 max_val
      <int> <int>   <dbl>
    1     1     1  0.827 
    2     1     2  1.04  
    3     2     1 -0.483 
    4     2     2 -0.131 
    5     3     1  1.19  
    6     3     2 -0.903 
    7     4     1  0.781 
    8     4     2  0.0135
## with a typo in na.rm argument    

tab %>% 
   group_by(grp1, grp2) %>% 
   summarise("max_val" = max(val, ns.rm = T))



# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   grp1 [4]
   grp1  grp2 max_val
  <int> <int>   <dbl>
1     1     1    1   
2     1     2    1.04
3     2     1    1   
4     2     2    1   
5     3     1    1.19
6     3     2    1   
7     4     1    1   
8     4     2    1  
### Using max function on a vector 

max(c(1, 2, 3), ns.rm = T)
[1] 3
max(c(1, 2, 3), ns.rm = T)
[1] 3
max(c(1, 2, 3), na.rm = T)
[1] 3
max(c(1, 2, 3, NA), ns.rm = T)
[1] NA
max(c(1, 2, 3, NA), na.rm = T)
[1] 3
```

Does anybody know if ns.rm is a legitimate input argument of any R function? 
If not, why there is no warning that the argument used is not used appropriately?

Comment: Can replicate the problem with R version 3.6.1, and dplyr version 0.8.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `ns.rm` is not a legitimate input argument but what is happening here is `ns.rm = T` is considered as new input in the vector which is passed in `max` where `T` is considered as 1.

```
max(c(1, 2, 3), ns.rm = T)
#[1] 3
```

is actually interpreted as

```
max(c(1, 2, 3), 1)
#[1] 3
```

and

```
max(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.33), ns.rm = T)
#[1] 1
```

is interpreted as

```
max(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.33), 1)
```

and

```
max(c(1, 2, 3, NA), ns.rm = T)
#[1] NA
```

is actually

```
max(c(1, 2, 3, NA), 1)
#[1] NA
```

---

Similarly, for the dataframe

```
set.seed(123)
tab <- data.frame(grp1 = sort(rep(1:4, 5)), 
                  grp2 = rep(c(1:2), 10),
                  val = rnorm(20))
```

By using the right way, we get numbers as

```
library(dplyr)
tab %>%  group_by(grp1, grp2) %>%  summarise(max_val = max(val, na.rm = T))

#   grp1  grp2 max_val
#  <int> <int>   <dbl>
#1     1     1  1.56  
#2     1     2  0.0705
#3     2     1  0.461 
#4     2     2  1.72  
#5     3     1  1.22  
#6     3     2  0.360 
#7     4     1  0.701 
#8     4     2  1.79
```

Now if we use `ns.rm = T`

```
tab %>%  group_by(grp1, grp2) %>% summarise(max_val = max(val, ns.rm = T))

#   grp1  grp2 max_val
#  <int> <int>   <dbl>
#1     1     1    1.56
#2     1     2    1   
#3     2     1    1   
#4     2     2    1.72
#5     3     1    1.22
#6     3     2    1   
#7     4     1    1   
#8     4     2    1.79
```

Notice where `max_val` was less than 1 in the above groups is now replaced with 1 while using `ns.rm` since `T` is interpreted as 1.

Also, note that this is not limited to `ns.rm` only, you can use any character here.

```
max(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.33), a = T)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! There is one more thing that doesn't make sense to me and that's the fact that when writing `max(c(1, 2, 3), ns.rm =T)` the fourth value (`ns.rm`) should be interpreted as the fourth value under the name ns.rm (am I right here?), and this usually should be done by using a string, e.g. `max(1, 2, 3, "ns.rm" = T)`.  Since I do not have an argument under the name `ns.rm` in my global environment I would expect that this kind of writing would return an error.

Comment: @TalKozlovski No..that is not necessary. See `c(a = 1, b = 2)` gives a named vector with `a` and `b` as names when `a` and `b` are not present in my global environment. Additionally using arguments with quotes works the same way. `c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)`. So you can use them with or without quotes, it works the same way.